# How to replace all 'None's in a complex (nested) structure of lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested

Say I have a complex structure, consisting of nested dictionaries and lists. For example:

```
test_variable = [{'key1': [{'sub_key1': None}], 'key2': 'Value2'}, {'Key3': None}]
```

Is there anyway I can find and replace all of the `None's`, and replace them with, say, `'book'`? I do know how to access each entry/key/value, but I'm looking for a way that works for any kind of given structure (no matter how nested), and not just the above example.

I have this code for a given structure, for example:

```
for key in test_dict:
    if isinstance(test_dict, list):
        for item in test_dict[key]:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                for sub_key in item:
                    if item[sub_key] == None:
                        item[sub_key] = 'Book'
```

But I want something to work for ***any*** given structure.

Comment: NameError - is that your problem? Create a real [mre] - fix your errors first.

Comment: You need to recurse into your data and find them.

Comment: Also other error ... you can not assing a list to  a difference of 2 variables.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: I just updated my question to add some code.

Comment: @PatrickArtner My problem is, these Nones will cause me problem in future. I need to change them to an string.

Comment: You need a recursive function which tests whether you need to iterate over a list or dict. Is your structure such that there will only ever be a None as a value in a dict? And not, for example a None as an element of a list?

Comment: quamrana, Thank you! That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this is actually a really neat & tricky problem; to be able to remove all the "complexity" from our nested list and dive deep into our `None's`!

> I'm assuming the structure follows the one provided in the example (nested lists & dictionaries),
> though it can handle even more complicated structures (i.e. it can solve *any* form of nested dictionaries within lists and vice-versa)*

One can achieve the that by **recursively** iterating through the list's entrees (or dictionary's values) and checking their types then acting accordingly, until reaching a dictionary who's key value is `None`:

```
def none_eliminator(structure):
    if type(structure) == dict:  # Check whether the (main or sub) structure is a dictionary
        for thing in structure:  # If so, loop over its key values not keys themselves
            if structure[thing] is None:
                structure[thing] = 'insert_something'
            elif type(structure[thing]) == list or type(structure[thing]) == dict:  # In case the key's value was another dictionary or list
                none_eliminator(structure[thing])  # Iterate over it again until finding a key with a value of type "None"!

    else:  # (If list)
        for thing in structure:  # Iterate over all main entrees of the list
            if type(thing) == list:
                none_eliminator(thing)  # Keep looping over its sub entrees (thing) until it's a dictionary

            elif type(thing) == dict:  # Nested dictionary within a list
                for key in thing:
                    if type(thing[key]) == list:  # Just in case the key's value was a list itself
                        none_eliminator(thing[key])

                    if type(thing[key]) == dict:  # Just in case the key's value was a dictionary itself
                        none_eliminator(thing[key])

                    if thing[key] is None:
                        thing[key] = 'insert_something'

    return structure
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How would you go about if the main structure is a dictionary, and not a list?

Comment: @tajir12457 In that case you would need to add an extra "guard" to check whether the main structure was a dictionary or not (since you don't need to loop over dictionary keys, but their values) and act accordingly. Check updated answer for implementation!